# Profiling mysql in realtime - find long running queries

Tags: mysql, linux

From the command line (linux) how can i zero in on long running mysql queries?

For exammple, I can use "top" on a linux box and see that mysqld is hogging lots of memory.  Are there any mysql command line commands i can use to go into further details and narrow down the culprit queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) shows the currently running queries. You can also tell mysql to create a slowlog, a log of all queries taking more than a certain time to complete.

Comment: I looked at mytop but its not something available by default so this is no use.  slowlog sounds interesting though

Comment: Installing that script is not a heavy operation. Why is that a problem?  MySQL slow query log docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: As i work with several sites and normally do not control full access to the server.  So i am looking for techniques/tools that will be possible on most linux distros with mysqld on

Comment: Running `mysqladmin processlist` often (via `watch` or manually) gives some kind of realtime status. mytop does more tricks but that should give you something at least.